# can microsoft detect pirate licence after formatted & installed ubuntu in hard disk?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I was using windows pirated version, but now i am using ubuntu 12.0 in same computer. I have full formatted my hard disk also.

I request you please give me answer for :

1. can Microsoft trace previously pirated license from Computer HDD.
2. what is the best HDD formatting method/software so Microsoft will not trace license from HDD. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you aren't using a pirated version of windows, they have no case against you. Welcome to Ubuntu, and legal computing!

Comment: No legal advice here too but mere formatting will **not** delete data on your drive. Previous files can be easily recovered unless they were completely **overwritten**.

Answer (score 2):

> Can Microsoft trace previously pirated license from Computer HDD.

Yes. It is possible to redo a format to some extent (with "testdisk"). But doing so would probably be far more costly then letting it slip since they need to get there hands on your system (and that probably requires a court order in most countries).

Mind you: if you bought the system from a store that is a chance you already paid for windows (prior to windows 8 you would have a sticker on the system with the serial; windows 8 seems to store the serial in bios(?)).

> What is the best HDD formatting method/software so Microsoft will not trace license from HDD. ?

Best method? Throw away the harddisc and get a brand new one.

Technically you can use tools to zero-fill your disc several times to make sure all was erased (since formatting most times does not erase the disc but removes just the partition table (short version ;) )) but a new harddisc is the least time consuming method.

Comment: From a technical perspective there's a very important question: What sort of access does Microsoft have to the hardware? If they raid your home and cart the hardware away, then they can employ forensic techniques to recover old data, as Rinzwind suggests. Similar comments might apply if Microsoft breaks into your computer remotely. If you're just Joe Average, though, chances are Microsoft won't be bothering with such techniques, and things like browser cookies won't reveal that you used to be running anything but Linux.

Comment: In Holland they are not allowed without a court order. And those are not issued for targeting 1 single person unless it is proven that person is profiting from it (ie. selling pirated copies)(but that might change since as of y-day we have an all out ban on downloading from "illegal sources").